# Phoenix: Convert String column to Integer column

Tags: hadoop, apache-phoenix

I am looking for a Built-in UDF or any other method to convert values of a string column to integer in my phoenix table for sorting using SELECT and ORDER BY. I searched in the apache language Manual, but no use. Any other suggestions also welcome.

Actual Query

```
select "values" from "test_table"
```

I tried below approach but did not work

```
select TO_NUMBER("values", '\u00A4') from "test_table"
```

Comment: CAST(values as INTEGER)?

Comment: getting error org.apache.phoenix.schema.TypeMismtachException : Error 203 (22005): Type mismatch. VARCHAR and INTEGER for "values"

Answer (score 3):

TO_NUMBER returns decimal but you can cast the result to INTEGER

SELECT CAST(TO_NUMBER(MY_COLUMN) AS INTEGER) FROM MY_DB

Comment: I think there is one typo, it should be  SELECT CAST(TO_NUMBER(MY_COLUMN) AS INTEGER) FROM MY_DB

Answer (score 0):

```
select TO_NUMBER(values) from test_table;
```

see https://phoenix.apache.org/language/functions.html#to_number

Comment: This converts to DECIMAL, which may not be what the user wants.